# ml-pipeline pod of kubeflow deployment is in CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I have very limited hands-on over the kubeflow setup. I have deployed a kubeflow pipeline on an EKS cluster with S3 connectivity for the artifacts. All the pods are up and running except the ml-pipeline deployment and also ml-pipeline-persistence agent deployment is failing due to the dependency on the ml-pipeline.

I am facing the below error while checking the logs of the pods:

```
I0321 19:19:49.514094       7 config.go:57] Config DBConfig.ExtraParams not specified, skipping
F0321 19:19:49.812472       7 client_manager.go:400] Failed to check if Minio bucket exists. Error: Access Denied.
```

Had anyone faced similar issues, I am not able to find many logs which could help me to debug the issue.

Also, the credentials consumed by the ml-pipeline deployment to access the bucket have all the required permissions.

Comment: did you ever find the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the S3 permissions assigned to the aws credentials you set for MINIO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & MINIO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. That is what caused the same error for me.
Although the auto-rds-s3-setup.py setup program provided by the aws distribution of kubeflow can create the s3 bucket, the credentials passed in to MINITO have to enable access to that bucket. So they are primarily for reusing an existing s3 bucket.